# reading an iso15693 nfc tag with flutter_nfc_kit

Tags: flutter, nfc, rfid, iso-15693

I'm trying to read data form an iso15693 nfc tag.  I can detect the tag but based on the response values almost all being blank or false I feel like I won't be able to read it.  I'm new to flutter_nfc_kit.  I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong, or if the response means my tag is not readable using flutter_nfc_kit.  Here's my code.  This function is triggered by a single button on the home page of my otherwise blank flutter app:

```
 void startScanning() async {
setState(() {
  scanning = true;
});

var availability = await FlutterNfcKit.nfcAvailability;
if (availability != NFCAvailability.available) {
  print("ERROR NFC NOT AVAILABLE");
  return;
}

var tag = await FlutterNfcKit.poll();
print(jsonEncode(tag));
```

}

output:

> I/flutter (15657): {"type":"iso15693","standard":"ISO 15693","id":"B47C7751002702E0","atqa":"","sak":"","historicalBytes":"","hiLayerResponse":"","protocolInfo":"","applicationData":"","manufacturer":"","systemCode":"","dsfId":"00","ndefAvailable":false,"ndefType":"","ndefCapacity":0,"ndefWritable":false,"ndefCanMakeReadOnly":false,"webUSBCustomProbeData":null}

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you are able to read the card with the flutter_nfc_kit to a level.
As you see the communication is happening and you are able to get the Tag UID.
Are you using Android or IOS? With iPhone you have limited functions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).